# ReferenceError: window is not defined

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to run [the Pocket-Island game by Wooga](https://github.com/wooga/Pocket-Island) and have installed all prerequisites listed at that page:

```
gem install rake
npm install -g less
npm install -g jslint
...
```

And then build the program successfully by running

```
rake all
```

And have now a new `build` directory:

```
app.js  css  images  index.html  ipad.html  templates  version
```

The app.js is 400k and looks like a minimized JavaScript file.

Then I try to run it with `node`:

```
#node ./app.js

/home/afarber/src/Pocket-Island/build/app.js:1
window.wooga.cas
^
ReferenceError: window is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/afarber/src/Pocket-Island/build/app.js:1:63)
    at Module._compile (module.js:446:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:464:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:353:31)
    at Function._load (module.js:311:12)
    at Array.0 (module.js:484:10)
    at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:190:38)
```

Being a complete **node.js** newbie, I suspect I'm missing something very obvious. Does anybody have an advice for me please?

I've looked into app.js and there is no `window.wooga.cas`, but there are several following variables:

```
window.wooga.castle.levels = .....
window.wooga.castle.entityDefinitions = .....
window.wooga.castle.version = "38da43a566503f3043576dafaf77f89363017397" ;
window.wooga.castle.tutorial = ....
```

So I think `app.js` is ok, but I must install it somewhere or maybe tell it where to find standard libraries? (I've installed **node.js** under `/usr/local/` )

I'm using a CentOS 6.2 and I'm actually an experienced Linux user.

**UPDATE:** More info (not sure if helpful):

```
# npm root
/home/afarber/src/Pocket-Island/build/node_modules
# npm --version
1.1.24
# node --version
v0.6.19
```

Comment: Erm. I think you misunderstood the purpose of this code. See, `window` object is an alias of Global object when JavaScript application is running within a browser. But there's no such object (by default) in Node.js environment. So it's probably that `app.js` is an application opened by `index.html`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

node is used for building only, not for running the game. It looks like the build itself worked fine so far. The `app.js` fie is to be loaded by `index.html` in a web browser.